# Calculate difference between observation in dependence of value of another variable

Tags: r, transformation, dplyr, logfile

I have an app record and want to calculate the time between two specific events.

My record structure looks like this:

```
    appdata <- data.frame(userid = c(1,1,1,1,1), dayid = c(32,32,32,32,32), activity = c("appstart","levelup","appclose","appstart","appclose"), datesec = c(2670,2726,2755,2787,4161))

    appdata
      userid dayid activity datesec
    1      1    32 appstart    2670
    2      1    32  levelup    2726
    3      1    32 appclose    2755
    4      1    32 appstart    2787
    5      1    32 appclose    4161
```

I want to know for one day how long the user was active. So I have to calculate the differences between each appstart and appclose and then build the sum, so here: (2755-2670) + (4161-2755) = 1459.

The new dataset should look like this:

```
    appdata2 <- data.frame(user = c(1), dayid = c(32), usagetime_in_sec = c(1491))

    appdata2
      user dayid usagetime_in_sec
     1    1    32             1459
```

Here is my basic approach, but I don't know how to tell R to always calculate the difference between an appstart and the next appclose event:

```
    apdata2 <- appdata %>% 
      group_by(userid, dayid) %>%
      summarise(usagetime_in_sec = sum(datsec(type == "appclose") - datesec(type == "appstart")))
```

Comment: `(2755-2670) + (4161-2755) ` I think this should be `(2755-2670) + (4161-2787) ` since `appstart` was 2787.

Comment: You're right, I've been editing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close. I think you need something like

```
library(dplyr)

appdata %>%
  group_by(userid, dayid) %>%
  summarise(usagetime_in_sec = sum(datesec[activity == "appclose"] - 
                                   datesec[activity == "appstart"]))


#   userid dayid usagetime_in_sec
#    <dbl> <dbl>            <dbl>
#1      1    32             1459
```

However, make sure you have equal number of "appclose" and "appstart" `activity` otherwise it might mess up the calculation.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know that R automatically goes through the order of events.

Comment: @Scijens you are welcome. Yes, if you have same length it will perform the calculation elementwise. Check `sum(c(5, 3) - c(4, 1))` Here , it will do `5-4 ` and `3-1` and then `sum` them `1 + 2 = 3`.